# In windows, how do I find out a folders sort by parameters

Tags: windows, powershell

I am building an image viewing app in Node.js. I noticed that in Windows, the pictures in a folder can be sorted by name, size, status, type, date and tags etc, and grouped after sorting by the same list and more.

Is there a way of getting the sort parameters or maybe just retrieving the sorted list of files, matching the regular expression **`/\.(jpg|jpg_large|jpeg|jpe|jfif|jif|jfi|jpe|gif|png|ico|bmp|webp|svg)$/i`**, as an array (ex: `['c:\man.jpg', 'c:\woman.jpg']` using Powershell?

EDIT:

This article got me closer to a solution. https://cyberforensicator.com/2019/02/03/shellbags-forensics-directory-viewing-preferences/

Unfortunately it doesn't explain how to get the nodelist value for a given folder so I used an app called shellbagsview from nirsoft to get this value. In any case, if the value is found the rest is easy. I have included a sample python script which explains how this is done here.

```
from winreg import *


# Registry is of the form:
# HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1375\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}
# where 1375 is a value called the NodeList, and {5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7} is a value under Shell chosen based on creation date. It is a good idea to look at the registry after getting the nodelist from shellbagsview
folder_reg_path = "Software\\Classes\\Local Settings\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\Shell\\Bags\\1375\\Shell\\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}"

# the size of icons used by the folder
def get_folder_icon_size(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'IconSize')
        return '%d pixels' % (value[0])

# the folder view. details, list, tiles e.t.c       
def get_logical_view_mode(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'LogicalViewMode')
        logical_view_mode_dict = {1 : "Details view", 2 : "Tiles view", 3 : "Icons view", 4 : "List view", 5 : "Content view"}
        return logical_view_mode_dict[value[0]]


# folder view is based on view mode. so you can have a  logical view mode of icons view with a view mode of large icons for instance    
def get_folder_view_mode(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'Mode')
        # view_mode 7 is only available on xp. A dead os
        view_mode_dict = {1 : "Medium icons", 2 : "Small icons", 3 : "List", 4 : "Details", 5 : "Thumbnail icons", 6 : "Large icons", 8 : "Content"}
        return view_mode_dict[value[0]]


# how is the folder being sorted
def get_folder_sort_by(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'Sort')
        folder_sort_dict = {"0E000000" : "Date Modified", "10000000" : "Date Accessed", "0F000000" : "Date Created", "0B000000" : "Type", "0C000000" : "Size", "0A000000" : "Name", "02000000" : "Title", "05000000" : "Tags"}
        # we get a byte value which we will hexify and get a rather long string
        # similar to : 000000000000000000000000000000000100000030f125b7ef471a10a5f102608c9eebac0c000000ffffffff
        reg_value = value[0].hex()
        # now for this string, we need to get the last 16 strings. then we now get the first 8 out of it. so we will have
        folder_sort_dict_key = (reg_value[-16:][:8]).upper()
        return folder_sort_dict[folder_sort_dict_key]

# in what order is the folder being sorted. ascending or descending???
def get_folder_sort_by_order(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'Sort')
        folder_sort_dict = {"01000000" : "Ascending", "FFFFFFFF" : "Descending"}
        # we get a byte value which we will hexify and get a rather long string
        # similar to : 000000000000000000000000000000000100000030f125b7ef471a10a5f102608c9eebac0c000000ffffffff
        reg_value = value[0].hex()
        # now for this string, we need to get the last 16 strings. then we now get the last 8 out of it. so we will have
        folder_sort_dict_key = (reg_value[-16:][-8:]).upper()
        return folder_sort_dict[folder_sort_dict_key]


icon_size = get_folder_icon_size(folder_reg_path)
logical_view_mode = get_logical_view_mode(folder_reg_path)
view_mode = get_folder_view_mode(folder_reg_path)
sorted_by = get_folder_sort_by(folder_reg_path)
sorted_by_order = get_folder_sort_by_order(folder_reg_path)
print ('The folder icon size is %s' % icon_size)
print('The folder logical view mode is %s' % logical_view_mode)
print('The folder view mode is %s' % view_mode)
print('The folder is sorted by %s in %s order' % (sorted_by, sorted_by_order))
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript` and `nodejs`? o.O

Comment: Because the app is being written in node and there might be a library for this

Comment: Where does the folder come from? Have you registered a shell extension?

Comment: take a look at "get-childitem" and "sort-object"

Comment: It can be any folder on windows. When you open a folder and do a right click, you will see an option for sort by and group by. I want to find out what parameters are being used to do this and also figure out a way to get the correct results

Comment: Get child item works but I need to know how the files are being sorted in the folder. gci -af returns the list of files sorted by name regardless of how I sort or group the folder

Comment: I get it could be any folder but how does the user choose? Do they type it? Right click folder? Send To?

Comment: It's an image viewing app where you open one image, and it loads all the image file names in the current directory into an array. So I want to load the image file names according to the folders grouping.

Answer (score 1):

The question itself and
the environment to run this in is unclear.

As you reference PowerShell and a RegEx to limit to specific extensions,

With this sample tree:

```
> tree /f a:\
A:\
└───Test
        boy.bmp
        child.ico
        girl.gif
        man.jpg
        woman.jpg
```

this script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path A:\Test -File |
 Where-Object Extension -match '\.(jpg|jpg_large|jpeg|jpe|jfif|jif|jfi|jpe|gif|png|ico|bmp|webp|svg)$' |
  Sort-Object Name | 
   Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

yields:

```
["A:\\Test\\boy.bmp","A:\\Test\\child.ico","A:\\Test\\girl.gif","A:\\Test\\man.jpg","A:\\Test\\woman.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IShellView` implementation (the file list part of Explorer) asks its `IShellBrowser` for a stream when it needs to load/save its state. My suggestion would be to host a `IExplorerBrowser` instance "browsed to the folder" and ask the view for its items. I don't know if you can ask it about which column it has sorted by but just getting the items in sorted order should be enough for your needs.

I don't know how to this in a scripting language but I assume PS supports enough COM for it to be possible.